# ffmpeg export without color loss

Tags: ffmpeg, colors

I'm trying to add a watermark to a video through ffmpeg, but all the exports result in loss of color information. I would like to retain the same color information as the original video, how do I do that?

Currently, I use this code:

```
./ffmpeg -i input.MOV -loop 1 -i logo.png -codec:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset medium -filter_complex "
```

I realised the only way to not lose the color information is to set -crf to 0 and -preset to veryslow, but it results in a really large file size. (2 times the size of original video, which is not effective)

I also get this error when I run ffpmeg:

```
[swscaler @ 0x117577000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
```

[See Image comparison here -- the blacks on the export were not as "black" as original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wakTt.jpg)

**ffprobe -show_streams for Original File**

```
ffprobe version 4.3.1-tessus  https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'IMG_0930-BenjaminWong.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2020-12-22T11:31:49.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:30.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 14688 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 252 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-12-22T11:31:49.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1080x1920, 14430 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-12-22T11:31:49.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : H.264
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=aac
codec_long_name=AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)
profile=LC
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/44100
codec_tag_string=mp4a
codec_tag=0x6134706d
sample_fmt=fltp
sample_rate=44100
channels=2
channel_layout=stereo
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/44100
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=1321751
duration=29.971678
bit_rate=252820
max_bit_rate=256000
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=1293
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:creation_time=2020-12-22T11:31:49.000000Z
TAG:language=und
TAG:handler_name=Core Media Audio
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=High
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1/60
codec_tag_string=avc1
codec_tag=0x31637661
width=1080
height=1920
coded_width=1088
coded_height=1920
closed_captions=0
has_b_frames=1
sample_aspect_ratio=N/A
display_aspect_ratio=N/A
pix_fmt=yuvj420p
level=40
color_range=pc
color_space=bt709
color_transfer=bt709
color_primaries=bt709
chroma_location=left
field_order=unknown
timecode=N/A
refs=1
is_avc=true
nal_length_size=4
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=30/1
avg_frame_rate=30/1
time_base=1/600
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=18000
duration=30.000000
bit_rate=14430480
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=8
nb_frames=900
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:creation_time=2020-12-22T11:31:49.000000Z
TAG:language=und
TAG:handler_name=Core Media Video
TAG:encoder=H.264
[/STREAM]
```

**ffprobe -show_streams for Exported File (added filter & watermark)**

```
ffprobe version 4.3.1-tessus  https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'IMG_0930-BenjaminWong_watermarked_1080h264-5.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:30.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5141 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1080x1080, 5003 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=High
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1/60
codec_tag_string=avc1
codec_tag=0x31637661
width=1080
height=1080
coded_width=1088
coded_height=1088
closed_captions=0
has_b_frames=2
sample_aspect_ratio=N/A
display_aspect_ratio=N/A
pix_fmt=yuvj420p
level=32
color_range=pc
color_space=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
chroma_location=left
field_order=unknown
timecode=N/A
refs=1
is_avc=true
nal_length_size=4
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=30/1
avg_frame_rate=30/1
time_base=1/15360
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=460800
duration=30.000000
bit_rate=5003599
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=8
nb_frames=900
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:language=und
TAG:handler_name=VideoHandler
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=aac
codec_long_name=AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)
profile=LC
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/44100
codec_tag_string=mp4a
codec_tag=0x6134706d
sample_fmt=fltp
sample_rate=44100
channels=2
channel_layout=stereo
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/44100
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=1321898
duration=29.975011
bit_rate=128780
max_bit_rate=128780
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=1292
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:language=und
TAG:handler_name=Core Media Audio
[/STREAM]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "loss of color information" ? Show e.g. an ffprobe dump of meta info to help describe how you determine this?

Comment: Hi @Caius Jard, I am looking at it by eye (comparison of the videos side by side -- the blacks of the exports were not as black as the original).. I can attach video screenshots here.

Comment: Sure, but you should still post the info described. It would help us debug the difference

Comment: Ok I've added an image, you can take a look -- may I know how can I find the ffprobe dump of meta info?

Comment: [ffprobe documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html)

Comment: OK I have added some metadata

Comment: Show your actual ffmpeg command (it has been truncated) and the complete log.

Comment: I guess you can try different combinations of `-crf` and `-preset` until you find one that is acceptable. If you are targeting a specific file size maybe try with [two pass encoding](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#twopass).